# Angular Material data source not found in seprate module other that app module

Tags: angular, angular-material

In my solution, I have created admin module and there are 5 components inside that admin module and I have declare all this components in the admin module. But when I'm using the material table in any of component, it is throwing error tha mat-table not found and
if I use table mat-table dataSource="listData"
Then it shows dataSource not found, in other words, it is not able to find the material module components.

I removed the component declaration from admin module and add that in the app module and error not coming but I want to use the admin module and declare these component ?

Any suggestions where I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you put little more piece of code to give more understanding of what you are asking?

Comment: you need to declare your component in the module that contains your mat-table and then import that module in other modules that you are gonna use

Comment: I have declared the components in the admin module but it's not working, I have to add the component in the app module then only it works and let me use formmodule, material controls etc in my components.